# How can I run multiple spec folders in rspec with one command?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm working on a gem for myself that is kind of a library of different features that I use frequently across Rails applications. As such, this gem is structured with many different 'sub-gems' each relating to one behavior. You can see my folder structure here:

[image]

Each of the three folders: 'configurable', 'injectable' and 'defaultable', have their own lib and spec folders.

I'm looking for a way to run 'rspec' from the command line in the base application directory (simple_skills) and have it run the main spec folder for simple skills, as well as each of the sub spec folders found in the folders I mentioned above, rather than having to go into each directory individually and manually run the tests from there:

How can I tie all of the different sub spec folders together to run all of them together when I run 'rspec' from the command line?

(Edited last line for clarity)

Comment: Did you try something like `rspec configurable/spec injectable/spec defaultable/spec`?

Comment: Thanks for the response! yeah that would work, but I should have been more clear about what I wanted, sorry about that. I want to be able to just run 'rspec' and have them all connect. I want to avoid having to string so many commands together (especially as I continue to add more sub folders to the gem) if at all possible.

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://blog.codingspree.net/2012/04/26/overwriting_rake_spec_task.html) will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your shell:

```
rspec `find . -type d -name spec`
```

The inner command will effectively find all folders named `spec` under current folder and run `rspec` for all of them. You might also alias this to save keystrokes:

```
alias rss="find . -type d -name spec -exec rspec {} \;"
```

Put the above into your shell’s `.rc` file and type

rss

to run `rspec` on all these folders.

Comment: ignore my last comment. I didn't even read your update, lol. I figured it out.